# Positioning and Height not working correctly in Firefox/IE

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am in the middle of building a responsive landing page for a company and the position of the CTA is refusing to work outside of chrome. Here is is working perfectly in chrome, reducing in size as I want it to: http://hydraservers.net/builds/

The following CSS is achieving that.

```
#page1Container {
    max-height: 700px;
    min-height: 700px;
}

#page1Background {
    background: #c5c5c5 url(../../../media/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 23.5%;
}

#page1Container .page1CTA {
    width: 1400px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

#page1Container .page1CTA #page1CTApos {
    position: relative;
    top: 26%;
}
```

Along with the following DIV structure:

```
<div id="page1Container">
    <div id="page1Background">
        <div id="adjustMe" class="page1CTA">
            <div id="page1CTApos">
                <h1><?php echo $config['homeHead1']; ?></h1>
                <h2><?php echo $config['homeHead2']; ?></h2>
                <div class="page1Button"><a href="get-started.php">Start Your Free Month</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Chrome is absolutely nailing what I want to achieve, but Firefox and IE are both falling over. Any ideas of what I am missing? Bare in mind the responsive nature of the background.

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified the code a bit. Try adding a margin to the top of the H1 rather than using positioning on the #page1CTApos element:

```
#page1Container{
    height: 700px;
    background: #c5c5c5 url(../../../media/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 23.5%;
}
#page1Container > div{
    width: 1400px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
#page1Container h1{
    margin-top:26%
}

<div id="page1Container">
    <div>
        <h1><?php echo $config['homeHead1']; ?></h1>
        <h2><?php echo $config['homeHead2']; ?></h2>
        <div class="page1Button"><a href="get-started.php">Start Your Free Month</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see where you are going with that. The h1's margin seems to be messing with the position of the div it's in though, and the height of the DIV doesn't reduce correctly either as the window gets more narrow: http://hydraservers.net/builds/index2.php

Comment: Try adding overflow:hidden to #page1Container > div

Comment: And you'll also need to add the background image to the header div:

#page1Container > div{
 background: #c5c5c5 url(../../../media/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 23.5%;
}

Comment: I'm not sure I follow with that last comment. I moved that code from #page1Container to #page1Container > div and it produced this: http://hydraservers.net/builds/index2.php

Maybe you could adjust your answer to clarify?

Comment: Also, the height of the background div isn't dynamic anymore because of the fixed height in #page1Container