# Take in parent divs (dynamic) height, and set child div to same height

Tags: jquery

If I have two divs, the parent of which (let's call it #parent) is dynamic in height, is there any way to keep a child div (let's call it #child) at the same height using jQuery, and for that height to increase and decease as the parent div responsively changes height?

Comment: Why not just set the child height to 100%?

Comment: Firefox and IE can't seem to handle it when the parent div doesn't have a strict set height.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try...

```
var h = $("#parent").height();
$("#child").height(h);
```

Or

```
$("#child").height($("#parent").height()); //to save a line of code
```

Add the code right after whatever is changing the divs height. Whether that be on `$(document).ready()` or an custom function

Comment: Why not dispense with the temp var and go one step further? `$("#child").height($("#parent").height());`. Oh, and this won't be responsive to resizes.

Comment: @j08691 updated for you. I think its easier for beginners to jQuery to see the different uses of `height()` if they are broken up.

Comment: $(document).ready() isn't really what you are looking for, since the parent div may contain images, and other dynamic content. You should go with $(window).load(function(){   // Your code here }); instead. (worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by CSS, just set the child div height to 100%

```
#parent
{
//css of parent div
}
#child{
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: IE and Firefox can't seem to handle it when the parent div's height isn't strictly set, which I can't do in this instance.

Comment: It works fine in IE,i tried it without the parent's div height.

Comment: Here is the issue I am trying to find my way around. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863286/positioning-and-height-not-working-correctly-in-firefox-ie/19863570 Do you have any idea why the div won't play ball in IE or Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

display: inline-block worked for me. I had a nested ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat and the parents had always 0 height